# How to give `this` the value of caller Object that is an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, this

I know this is a pretty short question, but I was just wondering if we can short this:

`cn.link.split('/')[cn.link.split('/').length - 1]`

To this:

`cn.link.split('/')[this.length - 1]`
or something like this where `this` can be replaced by something to make this work.

NOTE:- `cn` is an object.

Comment: Why don't you assign it to a variable?

Comment: I can't, this is what actually happening```<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'assets/images/products/' + cn.link.split('/')[cn.link.split('/').length - 1] + '/pro_1.jpg'}```. Thus, I can't create a variable here LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.pop()` To get the last item of an array:

```js
const link = 'a/b/c/d/e'

const last = link.split('/').pop()

console.log(last)

const url = `assets/images/products/${link.split('/').pop()}/pro_1.jpg`

console.log(url)
```